# declaring a pointer to a two dimension array of void*

Tags: c++, pointers, declaration

I'm having trouble figuring out how to declare a pointer to an array of arrays of `void*`. (I can't use STL containers and the like because it's an embedded system.)

I have some data that I'm trying to group together in a structure. Mostly built-in data types, but then are these two arrays. The first one,

```
char *testpanel_desc[] = {...};
```

isn't a problem. In my structure I store a pointer to this array like so:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    ...
    char** panelDesc;
};
```

But then there's this one:

```
 void *testpanel_pointers[][4] = {...};
```

and I can't come up with a way to define a member of my structure that I can assign this array to. `void***` doesn't work because of the 4 in the original declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make life a bit simplier and use typedefs

```
identity<void*[4]>::type *panelDesc;
```

Or equivalent

```
typedef void *type[4];
type *panelDesc;
```

I doubt you know what the following means, but suffice it to say it's equivalent too

```
void *(*panelDesc)[4];
```

Note that based on type, it is not a "a pointer to a two dimension array of void*", much like `char**` is not a "pointer to a one dimension array of char*". But keeping the way you do it in the one-dimension case (pointing to the first element), this is the declaration you need.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't considering the problem in such terms (pointer to the first element), even though it makes perfect sense when you think about it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
void *testpanel_pointers[1][4] = {};

void* (*p)[1][4]; //pointer to a two dimensional array of pointers to void
p = &testpanel_pointers;
```